# why does this regex fail in PHP?

Tags: php, regex, email

I got the expression directly from [RegExr](http://regexr.com?2t00i), but PHP has a problem with the `=`

```
"/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/"
```

The expression is for matching email addresses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Escape the slash preceding the `=` (and the other slash in that expression). You use `/` as a delimiter, therefore if it occurs inside the pattern it has to be escaped.

```
"/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/"
```

should work, then.

Answer (score 3):

You used `/` as the delimiter marking the start and end of the pattern, but then also used that character within the pattern. You must either use a different delimiter, or escape instances of it within the pattern. If you meant to escape the equals signs, then you used the wrong slash.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `/` as delimiter. There are two `/` in the regex which are not escaped. Escape them as `\/`:

```
"/[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/"
                 ^^                                ^^
```